# Python - Filtering a list of tuples with lambda

Tags: python, list, lambda, filter, tuples

I try to update tuple values using another tuple.

```
grade = (('a', 10), ('b', 20), ('c', 30), ('d', 40))

factors = (('a', 1), ('b', 2))
```

Expected result:

```
result  = (('a', 11), ('b', 22), ('c', 30), ('d', 40))
```

What would be the right way to do this? , I tried the following code but it did not work. I would be happy to help

```
print(list(filter(lambda list_a: list(map(lambda x, y: x+ y, list_a[0], grade[1])) not in list(map(lambda x: x[0], factors)), grade)))
```

Comment: Why b is `12` and why not `22` ?

Comment: Time to learn list comprehensions.

Comment: And dictionaries.

Comment: @toRex You're right my mistake, I updated it

Comment: To improve your question please describe shortly what the update is expected to do. We may guess it by the result but it would help to have a clear specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
fact = dict(factors)
result = list(
    map(
        lambda x: (x[0], x[1] + fact.get(x[0], 0)), grade
    )
)
```

Comment: Is there any solution to do that without using dict?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use dictionaries, seem more suited for your task:

```
factors = dict(factors)
grade = dict(grade)
{k: grade[k] + factors[k] if k in factors.keys() else grade[k] for k  in grade.keys()}
```

Output:

```
{'a': 11, 'b': 22, 'c': 30, 'd': 40}
```

Comment: Is there any solution to do that without using dict?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a dict, and you can take advantage of its `get` method to get 0 for non existing keys:

```
grade = (('a', 10), ('b', 20), ('c', 30), ('d', 40))

factors = (('a', 1), ('b', 2))
factors = dict(factors)

new_grades = [(g[0], g[1] + factors.get(g[0], 0)) for g in grade]
print(new_grades)
# [('a', 11), ('b', 22), ('c', 30), ('d', 40)]
```

Comment: Is there any solution to do that without using dict?

Comment: This could be possible, but you have to get the value corresponding to a letter in factors. If you don't build a dict, you'll need a function that iterates on your tuples each time until it finds the one that contains the right letter. This is very inefficient. On the other side, once you have built the dict once, accessing the value associated with a letter is done directly without any iteration. That's much more efficient, and doesn't require you to write a function that will not be as good. So, do the right thing and enjoy!

Comment: And, as a side note, list comprehensions are usually faster than using map when you just want to build the list.

Answer (score 0):

Make `factors` a dict:

```
factors = dict(factors)
```

then use a dict comprehension to build a new `dict` using the existing association list `grades`:

```
result = {g: score + factors.get(g, 0) for g, score in grade}
```

If you really need a tuple of tuples, use

```
result = tuple((g, score + factors.get(g,0)) for g, score in grade)
```

Comment: Tried your code but it brings: `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 0, 'd': 0}`

Answer (score 0):

How about using Counters instead?

```
from collections import Counter

grade = Counter(dict(grade))
factors = Counter(dict(factors))
```

The the update is simply

```
grade += factors
```

or

```
grade.update(factors)
```